# Working with document term matrix in xgboost

Tags: r, xgboost, sentiment-analysis, tm

I am working on sentiment analysis in r. i've done making a model with naive bayes. but, i wanna try another one, which is xgboost. then, i got a problem when tried to make xgboost model because don't know what to do with my document term matrix in xgboost. Can anyone give me a solution?

i've tried to convert the document term matrix data to data frame. but it doesn't seem to work.

the code below describes how my current train & test data

```
library(tm)
dtm.tf <- VCorpus(VectorSource(results$text)) %>%
DocumentTermMatrix()

#split 80:20   
all.data <- dtm.tf
train.data <- dtm.tf[1:312,]
test.data <- dtm.tf[313:390,]
```

and i have xgboost template with another data set :

```
# install.packages('xgboost')
library(xgboost)
classifier = xgboost(data = as.matrix(training_set[-11]), 
                     label = training_set$Exited, nrounds = 10)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = as.matrix(test_set[-11]))
y_pred = (y_pred >= 0.5)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
cm = table(test_set[, 11], y_pred)
```

i want to use the xgboost template above to make my model using my current train & test data. what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the document term matrix into a sparse matrix. In your case that can be done via `sparseMatrix` function from the Matrix package (default with R):

```
sparse_matrix_tf <-  Matrix::sparseMatrix(i=dtm.tf$i, j=dtm.tf$j, x=dtm.tf$v,
                                              dims=c(dtm.tf$nrow, dtm.tf$ncol))
```

Then you can use this to feed it to xgboost and use the label form the dtm.tf.

```
classifier = xgboost(data = sparse_matrix_tf, 
                     label = dtm.tf$dimnames$Docs,
                     nrounds = 10).
```

Complete reproducible example below. I leave the splitting into 80 / 20 to you.

```
library(tm)
library(xgboost)

data("crude")
crude <- as.VCorpus(crude)
dtm.tf <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude)

sparse_matrix_tf <-  Matrix::sparseMatrix(i=dtm.tf$i, j=dtm.tf$j, x=dtm.tf$v,
                                              dims=c(dtm.tf$nrow, dtm.tf$ncol))

classifier = xgboost(data = sparse_matrix_tf, 
                     label = dtm.tf$dimnames$Docs,
                     nrounds = 10)
```

Comment: ok. thank you for your answer. then, how about the predicting & confusion matrix? how to call the train & test set ? because i got it from splitting dtm.tf

Comment: The sparse matrix is of the same length as the dtm.tf. You can do the same manipulations before training the xgboost classifier.

Comment: ok. i got the idea of your explanation. but, i got an error when i make confusion matrix. i don't know how to get target class since it was matrix. as you can see in my previous code the way i make the confusion matrix is : 
cm = table(test_set[, 11], y_pred)

Comment: when i run the following code :

cm = table(sparse_matrix_test, y_pred)

I got error 

Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors

Comment: try `table(dtm.tf$dimnames$Docs[testrange], y_pred)` where *testrange* is the range you used when creating sparse_matrix_test.

Comment: ok then. i'm done until confussion matrix. how about access column when i want to working with caret?